# How to customize the onMouseOver gitgraph-js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to utilize the library **@gitgraph/js** in my application (Note: I cannot use the React or NodeJS version, only the plain JS):
https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/tree/master/packages/gitgraph-js

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ben_Vins/fwcah5s0/7/

```
var myTemplateConfig = {
  // … any specific template configuration
  commit: {
    shouldDisplayTooltipsInCompactMode: true, // default = true
    tooltipHTMLFormatter: function(commit) {
      return "<b>BV" + commit.sha1 + "</b>" + ": " + commit.message;
    },
  }
};


// Instantiate the graph.
const gitgraph = GitgraphJS.createGitgraph(graphContainer, {
  mode: GitgraphJS.Mode.Compact,
  template: new GitgraphJS.templateExtend(GitgraphJS.TemplateName.Metro, myTemplateConfig ), 
});

// Simulate git commands with Gitgraph API.
const master = gitgraph.branch("master");
master.commit("Initial commit");

const develop = gitgraph.branch("develop");
develop.commit("Add TypeScript");

const aFeature = gitgraph.branch("a-feature");
aFeature
  .commit("Make it work")
  .commit({ subject: "Make it right", hash: "test" })
  .commit("Make it fast");

develop.merge(aFeature);
develop.commit("Prepare v1");

master.merge(develop).tag("v1.0.0");
```

By default, the result were too big, so I have applied a css to scale down the graph (the graph is an inline SVG without a cropbox property, so this is the only trick I could find).

What I would like to do:

1. Customize the tooltip of the onhover of the commits node (making it larger, change the text, change its css if possible)
2. Add a onclick event to capture the commit (in particular the commit hash to be used elsewhere in my application)

Extra points:

- The documentation is limited and the examples from 
  https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/tree/master/packages/stories/src/gitgraph-js/
  are in typescript. Are they also applicable for the JS version of gitgraph-js?
- Note that the documentation of **gitgraph.js** seemed more detailed i.e. https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/blob/master/packages/gitgraph-js/MIGRATE_FROM_GITGRAPH.JS.md but I was trying to use the next version i.e. **@gitgraph/js**

Comment: For the `commit` method, are the parameter really: subject and hash? I assume it should be **message** and **sha1**? I found that in the [gitgraph JS docu-v1](https://www.nicoespeon.com/gitgraph.js/v1/docs/Commit.html) --- I found in the code [GitHub - Commit-class](https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/blob/master/packages/gitgraph-core/src/commit.ts) that you are right, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out. I can add more colors to this as the author of the lib.

1. To customize the tooltip of a commit, you can provide a `renderTooltip()` custom function. It will give you the reference to the commit object, so you can customize at your will.
2. Same, you can pass a `onClick()` function that will give you the reference to the commit object

The examples are in TypeScript, but that's valid JS if you simply remove the types. Also, the gitgraph-js stories looks like they are React code, but they're not. They're simply wrapped in a React component so we could run them in Storybook along with the gitgraph-react ones.

With the latest version of the lib, you could try the following:

```js
const graphContainer = document.getElementById("graph-container");

// Instantiate the graph.
const withoutBranchLabels = GitgraphJS.templateExtend(GitgraphJS.TemplateName.Metro, {
  branch: { label: { display: false } },
});

const gitgraph = GitgraphJS.createGitgraph(graphContainer, {
  mode: GitgraphJS.Mode.Compact,
  template: withoutBranchLabels,
});

// Simulate git commands with Gitgraph API.
let storedCommit;

gitgraph
  .commit({ 
    subject: "Initial commit",
    onClick: (commit) => storedCommit = commit 
  })
  .commit({ 
    subject: "Another commit",
    onClick: (commit) => storedCommit = commit 
  })
  .commit({
    subject: "Do something crazy",
    renderTooltip,
    onClick: (commit) => storedCommit = commit
  });

gitgraph
  .branch("dev")
  .commit({
    subject: "Oh my god",
    renderTooltip,
  })
  .commit({
    subject: "This is a saxo!",
    renderTooltip,
  });

// Logs in console the sha1 of the clicked commit every 3s (for master branch only)
setInterval(() => storedCommit && console.log(`stored commit sha1: ${storedCommit.hashAbbrev}`), 3000)

// Custom tooltip renderer
function renderTooltip (commit) {
  const commitSize = commit.style.dot.size * 2;

  return createG({
    translate: { x: commitSize + 10, y: commitSize / 2 },
    children: [
      createText({ 
        fill: commit.style.dot.color,
        content: `BV${commit.hashAbbrev}: ${commit.subject}` 
      })
    ],
  });
}

// Helper functions to create SVGs
const SVG_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function createText(options) {
  const text = document.createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "text");
  text.setAttribute("alignment-baseline", "central");
  text.setAttribute("dominant-baseline", "central");
  text.textContent = options.content;

  if (options.bold) {
    text.setAttribute("font-weight", "bold");
  }

  if (options.fill) {
    text.setAttribute("fill", options.fill);
  }

  if (options.font) {
    text.setAttribute("style", `font: ${options.font}`);
  }

  if (options.anchor) {
    text.setAttribute("text-anchor", options.anchor);
  }

  if (options.translate) {
    text.setAttribute("x", options.translate.x.toString());
    text.setAttribute("y", options.translate.y.toString());
  }

  if (options.onClick) {
    text.addEventListener("click", options.onClick);
  }

  return text;
}


function createG(options) {
  const g = document.createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, "g");
  options.children.forEach((child) => child && g.appendChild(child));

  if (options.translate) {
    g.setAttribute(
      "transform",
      `translate(${options.translate.x}, ${options.translate.y})`,
    );
  }

  if (options.fill) {
    g.setAttribute("fill", options.fill);
  }

  if (options.stroke) {
    g.setAttribute("stroke", options.stroke);
  }

  if (options.strokeWidth) {
    g.setAttribute("stroke-width", options.strokeWidth.toString());
  }

  if (options.onClick) {
    g.addEventListener("click", options.onClick);
  }

  if (options.onMouseOver) {
    g.addEventListener("mouseover", options.onMouseOver);
  }

  if (options.onMouseOut) {
    g.addEventListener("mouseout", options.onMouseOut);
  }

  return g;
}
```

You can't just return HTML though, it must be SVG because the current renderer only handles SVG. That is surely less convenient than before, thus I encourage you to build helper functions like I did here. You can find helpers used in the stories too.

I hope that will be helpful. You can play with the new online playground too: https://codepen.io/nicoespeon/pen/arqPWb?editors=1010

Finally, I'm not maintaining the library much and I'm still looking for active maintainers: https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/issues/328